# How can we user material elements in innerHtml, example ' <mat-icon>?

Tags: angular, angular-material, innerhtml

I am getting html markup from backend side and I need to correctly render elements in UI.
I am trying append content with innerHtml, and getting from backend side dynamicly. And it can be anything containing html markup

I have this div

```
  <div [innerHTML]="html"
    ></div>
```

backend ts
`let markup = "<mat-icon mat-list-icon>folder</mat-icon>"`

front end ts
 `let html = markup`

Instead of folder icon, it displays "folder" text

Comment: You want to inject html as a result of function? If you are using Angular, how about you mark up your html with the mat-icon and set an ngif on it, with a condition to show or hide it?

Comment: I am getting html markup from backend side and I need to correctly render elements in UI

Comment: Are you sure you have the CSS classes for Mat Icon loaded? Inspect the element and check the material theme is loaded

Comment: yes I am sure, it is loaded, whole project working on material. The problem is connected with angular AOT, because when I used innerHtml, browser compilation already finished,There need to be way after innerHtml somehow call compilataton for that component again. but I couldn`t find yet

Comment: Not sure if this helps but, have you looked at the ChangeDetectorRef in Angular:  https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef  to re-render your content after html insertion.

Comment: I have tried it but not work again, anyway thank you!